# How to use `backspace` to navigate to the parent folder in Spacemacs?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs

When I use `C-f` to find a file in Spacemacs, how can I use `<backspace>` to navigate to the parent folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior if using the [Ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) completion engine.

Assuming you are using [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) (the default for Spacemacs) for your completion engine, there is a command `helm-find-files-up-one-level` which is bound to `C-l` in the `helm-find-files-map`.  If you want to bind your backspace key to that function you can do this:

`(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "<backspace>") 'helm-find-files-up-one-level)`

You can put this into your `dotspacemacs/user-config` section and re-evaluate your init file, or just evaluate it in the `*scratch*` buffer to try it out first.

Comment: my friend has such configuration which to navigate to upper folder, but he doesn't do anything with the init.el. I am wondering is there any command to do this.

Comment: If you use `Ivy` for the completion back-end, that is the default behavior.  It is possible your friend is using that, or maybe a different version of spacemacs?

Comment: yes, Ivy is the plugin I need.